# Duplicate values in pivot table filter list

Tags: excel, filter, pivot-table, vba

I have a rather large filter table derived from a table containing thousands of entries. This uses calculated values for fault diagnosis and for assessing the system availability.

I am trying to filter the pivot table values to display only the most significant faults. The field I am attempting to filter contains floating point values, and the intention is that only entries with a number above a given value are displayed, (let's say > 0.01).

The code is:

```
Sub FilterPivotTable(pvtName As String, pvtField As String, rngMin As String)
' pvtName = name of pivot table
' pvtField = pivot table field to filter
' rngMin = range name containing the minimum value to filter on

Dim pvtItem As PivotItem
Dim vMin As Double
Dim x As Double

vMin = Range(rngMin).Value
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables(pvtName).PivotFields(pvtField)
    .ShowAllItems = True
    For Each pvtItem In .PivotItems
        x = CDbl(pvtItem.Name)
        pvtItem.Visible = (x >= vMin)
    Next
End With

' Change the cache setting
ActiveSheet.PivotTables(pvtName).PivotCache.MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsNone
ActiveSheet.PivotTables(pvtName).PivotCache.Refresh

End Sub
```

The routine runs correctly, hiding values less than the limit... except when the filter list has duplicate values! In this case, the first value is unticked, but other values remain ticked.

When I step through the macro, I can see the name string values, and the value of x appearing correctly in the local variables, but Excel doesn't seem to know which pvtItem it is actually looking at. The duplicate items already have state Visible = False before it is actioned in line pvtItem.Visible = (x >= vMin), and Excel seems to simply make the first value in the list with that name invisible rather than the actual item being examined.

My problem may be that I have multiple items in the list with the same name. Can I eliminate the duplicate names?

I don't have the "reputation" to post pictures, but the drop down filter list contains example entries as follows:

```
[ ] 0.0000125385802469136
[ ] 5.78703703703704E-06
[x] 5.78703703703704E-06
[ ] 0.0000326554232804233
[ ] 6.61375661375661E-06
[x] 6.61375661375661E-06
[x] 0.0000132275132275132
[ ] 1.65343915343915E-06
[x] 1.65343915343915E-06
etc.
```

e.g. the pvtItem.Name (string) is identical for the 2nd and 3rd items, 5th and 6th items, 8th and 9th items, etc. I have examined the raw data in the source table and the real values are also identical to the maximum displayed 30 digits including decimal points.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: did you try to round up these values and do filtering based on new rounded column?? I know it's not the answer but suggestion. I'm keen to know the reason of your problem, too.

Comment: Ok, there is one suggestion... Try to change you `For each` loop to run from last element to first. Therefore you would have `For i=.PivotItems.Count To 1 Step -1`. That problem could be similar to one with deleting rows which always should be done from last to first.

Comment: Well done you! I've added another column to the source table, rounded to 10 decimal places and then filtered on that column. The filtering worked. Brilliant. I may have exposed a bug in Excel pivot tables, but more likely it's a lack of knowledge on my part.

Comment: I tried your suggestion with the same result. Code is:    
For i = .PivotItems.Count To 1 Step -1
x = CDbl(ActiveSheet.PivotTables(pvtName).PivotFields(pvtField).PivotItems(i).Name)
ActiveSheet.PivotTables(pvtName).PivotFields(pvtField).PivotItems(i).Visible = (x >= vMin)
Next

Comment: OK. Next question: How do I add properly formatted code to comments?

Comment: you could delete comment and add it to your question using edit feature which is welcomed :) in comments you need to start with inverted comma (or what it's name? :)

Comment: Many thanks for your help KazJaw. I am happy that I have a solution to my problem.

Comment: This question should be closed as it has been answered.